# Problema al tratar de instanciar una clase de forma dinámica

Tags: javascript, typescript

Estoy tratando de crear instancias de las clases _0 , _1 y _2 de forma dinámica.

Pero en la clase DynamicClass que es donde estoy tratando de hacer dicho proceso me arroja un error y no tengo claro el cómo resolverlo.

si realizo el proceso de forma estatica osea de la forma siguiente:

```
return new _1().getProperty()
```

obtengo el resultado correcto,

pero necesito hacerlo de forma dinamina

```js
abstract class Auto {
  abstract getProperty();
}

class _0 extends Auto {
  getProperty() {
    return 400;
  }
}
class _1 extends Auto {
  getProperty() {
    return 2000;
  }
}
class _2 extends Auto {
  getProperty() {
    return 100;
  }
}

class DynamicClass {
  select() {
    let random: any = "_" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
    console.log(random);
    return new random().getProperty();
  }
}

console.log(new DynamicClass().select());
```

Comment: el detalle es que random es un string, lo ideal es que hagas un arreglos de tus clases y con el numero buscas ls posicion y luego la intancias

Answer (score 0):

Recuerda que en JS, las clases son funciones, así que puedes hacer algo como esto:

```js
const classes = {
  _0: class {
    get greetings() {
      return "Hi!";
    }
  }
};
const instance = new classes["_0"]();
console.log(instance.greetings);
```

Answer (score 0):

No puedes ejecutar la línea `new random()` porque `random` sólo es una variable que apunta a un `string`, no es un *constructable*.

Te propongo dos soluciones.

1. **Usar un mapa de clases.**
   De esta forma, poder sacar un elemento de forma dinámica por la clave e invocarlo para crear una instancia. Es la misma solución que propone @Luis Bedoya

```
interface ClassMap {
    [key: string]: new () => Auto
};

const classes: ClassMap = {
    '_0': class _0 extends Auto {
        getProperty() {
            return 400;
        }
    },
    '_1': class _1 extends Auto {
        getProperty() {
            return 2000;
        }
    },
    ...
};

class DynamicClass {
    select(): number {
        const random = this.getRandom();
        const instance = this.getInstance(random);
        return instance.getProperty();
    }

    private getRandom = (): string =>
        // Estaría bien poner ese 2 dinámico y no hardcoded
        // quizás con el número de keys del objeto classes, etc...
        `_${Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)}`;

    private getInstance = (random: string): Auto =>
        new classes[random]();
}

const dyn = new DynamicClass();
console.log(dyn.select());
```

2. **Usar `eval()` para ejecutar código por reflexión**
   Esta solución es sólo a nivel recreativo, **no** es recomendable usarse en producción. Usar `eval` es peligroso.
   En este caso no nos hace falta el mapa de clases.

```
// abstract class Auto {...}
// class _0 extends Auto {...}
// class _1 extends Auto {...}

class DynamicClass {
    select(): number {
        const random = this.getRandom();
        const instance = this.getInstance(random);
        return instance.getProperty();
    }

    private getRandom = (): string =>
        `_${Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)}`;

    private getInstance = (random: string): Auto =>
        eval(`new ${random}()`) as Auto;
}

const dyn = new DynamicClass();
console.log(dyn.select());
```

> En caso de que los constructores necesitasen argumentos (para hacerlo sencillo, sólo `string`, `number` o `boolean`), el método `getInstance` quedaría del siguiente modo

```
private getInstance = (random: string, ...args: (string | number | boolean)[]): Auto =>
    eval(`new ${random}(${args.join(',')})`) as Auto;
```

Espero que sirva.